# How can I return an error from a gRPC service?

Tags: ruby, error-handling, microservices, grpc

I have a simple gRPC service running in Ruby. Under some conditions, I want to return an error to the client in a controlled fashion, something like an HTTP status code with an error message. I don't see any clear way to do this from the documentation; what is the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 4):

After digging around a while, I think the correct answer will be to use `GRPC::BadStatus`, as described [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/5253c8f9a899450397a5e46e4923d01ac9a66a27/src/ruby/lib/grpc/errors.rb#L19-L29):

> BadStatus is an exception class that indicates that an error
>   occurred at either end of a GRPC connection.  When raised, it
>   indicates that a status error should be returned to the other end of a
>   `GRPC` connection; when caught it means that this end received a status
>   error.
>
> There is also subclass of BadStatus in this module for each
>   `GRPC` status. E.g., the `GRPC::Cancelled` class corresponds to status
>   `CANCELLED`.
>
> See https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpc/impl/codegen/status.h for detailed descriptions of each status code.

and so, raising an error like this

```
raise GRPC::BadStatus.new_status_exception(CANCELLED)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: `raise GRPC::Cancelled.new` should work as well.